# NHibernate criteria query using Max() projection

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I have to implement something like this using NHibernate

```
DetachedCriteria maxDateQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(FtpStatus.class);
ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
proj.add(Projections.max("datetime"));
proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("connectionid"));
maxDateQuery.setProjection(proj);

Criteria crit = s.createCriteria(FtpStatus.class);
crit.add(Subqueries.propertiesEq(new String[] {"datetime", "connectionid"}, maxDateQuery));

List<FtpStatus> dtlList = crit.list();
```

(This snippet is from [Hibernate criteria query using Max() projection on key field and group by foreign primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723803/hibernate-criteria-query-using-max-projection-on-key-field-and-group-by-foreig))

My problem is that Nhibernate doesn't implement "Subqueries.propertiesEq" which is used in this row:

```
crit.add(Subqueries.propertiesEq(new String[] {"datetime", "connectionid"}, maxDateQuery));
```

Could you please suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is *(talking about **NHibernate**)* to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. The query would look like this

```
// the below outer query, has essential feature
// ALIAS name "outer"
// and this is used here, in the "subquery"
var maxDateQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<MyEntity>("myEntity")
    .SetProjection(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("MyId"))
        .Add(Projections.Max("MyDate"))
        )
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty(
        Projections.Max("MyDate"),
        Projections.Property("outer.MyDate")) // compare inner MAX with outer current
        )
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("MyId", "outer.MyId")) // inner and outer must fit
    ;

// here ... the "outer" is essential, because it is used in the subquery
var list = session.CreateCriteria<Contact>("outer")
    .Add(Subqueries.Exists(maxDateQuery))
    ... // e.g. paging
    .List<MyEntity>();
```

And that will create query like this:

```
FROM [MyEntityTable] outer
WHERE exists 
(
  SELECT  myEntity.MyId
    , max(myEntity.MyDate) 
   FROM [MyEntityTable] myEntity
   WHERE    myEntity.MyId         = outer.MyId   // matching ID
   GROUP BY myEntity.MyId
   HAVING   max(myEntity.MyDate)  = outer.MyDate // matching max and current date
)
```

The same type of query *(even more complex)* in a `QueryOver` syntax can be found here:

- [Query on HasMany reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528760/)